# uniform convergence by $n^2 x$

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

Consider the piecewise continuous functions $f_n: [0, 1] → \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N$, with $$f_n (x)=\begin{cases} 
      xn^2 & ,x: [0,1/n] \\
      0 & ,x : (1/n,1] 
   \end{cases},$$

Check $f_n$ for pointwise and uniform convergence.

My idea on pointwise:
If $x = 0$, then $\lim = 0$
If $x ≠ 0$, then distinguish:
1st case: $x \in (1/n,1):$ by definition $0$, so also $\lim$
2nd case: $x \in (0,1/n]$: so $n^2x = (1/x)n^2x^2$, so zero sequence exists, since $x \neq 0$, $\lim = 0$ holds.

Does this make sense?

And can someone give me a hint at uniform convergence, because I'm confused right now.

Comment: A [brief introduction to posting math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) contains links to more detailed information.  If you like I will revise your post to give an illustration of how it works.

Comment: Use latex.For mathjax basic tutorials for this website , please [click here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/934187)

Comment: What you say makes no sense. If you distinguish the cases this way then you can't start taking limits wrt $n$.

Comment: Okay, but I separated all x from [0,1] and if x ≠ 0, you must look at (0,1] and due to the Definition we must which form has x

Answer (score 1):

A sequence of functions $f_n:D\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly convergent to some function $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ iff for all $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in D$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Now, consider your sequence of functions:

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}xn^2&,\text{ }x\in[0,\frac{1}{n}]\\0&,\text{ }x\in(\frac{1}{n},1)\end{cases}$$

As $n$ increases, $\frac{1}{n}$ decreases, so the interval over which $f_n(x)=0$ increases towards $[0,1]$, implying that $f_n(x)$ must converge to $f(x)=0$. So, we analyze:

$$|f_n(x)-0|<\epsilon$$

For any given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\max\limits_{[0,1]}\{f_n(x)\}=(\frac{1}{n})n^2=n$ (this is because $xn^2$ is an increasing for $x$). But if $\{f_n\}$ were uniformly convergent, this would mean that for any $\epsilon$, there exists some $N$ such that whenever $n\geq N$, $|n|<\epsilon$, which is obviously untrue. Thus, $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh yeah, it helps a lot, thank you very much

Comment: Okay, but I have another question: We are now supposed to check that integration and consequence boundary value formation are interchangeable here. I would say no, because it should be true: integral from 0 to 1 with lim (n -> inf) f(n)(x) dx = lim (n -> inf) (integral from 0 to 1 f(n)(x) dx). 
The first one should be zero, because lim is 0 and so is the integral, but I have difficulties to solve the second integral.